# Difference between @PathVariable("ownerId") String theOwner and @PathVariable String theOwner

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

is there any difference between `@PathVariable("ownerId") String theOwner` and `@PathVariable String theOwner` in `Spring MVC`.

I've gone through with the [Spring @PathVariable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller), but I'm not clear about the concept.

I found one difference by analyzing if the `uri parameter` is having the same name as the `variable name` , then you can directly store it in variable. Is this correct or you can post any other information related to this.

```
@GetMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
public String findOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") String theOwner, Model model) {
// implementation omitted
}

@GetMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
// implementation omitted
}
```

Comment: No there isn't. Unless you compile without parameter names then in the second case it will fail as the path variable cannot be resolved.

Comment: It's pretty good explained in the documentation. Not sure what else can be said.. Always use `PathVariable("ownerId")` because you don't want to introduce bugs because you forgot some compiler parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that first option allow you to change parameter name in your method, you can use `theOwner` and not `ownerId`.

This can be useful for example if you have a class member with same name `ownerId`

Answer (score 2):

The Spring MVC [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) is pretty clear on how it works:

> To process the `@PathVariable` annotation, Spring MVC needs to find the matching URI template variable by name. You can specify it in the annotation:
>
> ```
> @GetMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
> public String findOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") String theOwner, Model model) {
>     // implementation omitted
> }
> ```
>
> Or if the URI template variable name matches the method argument name you can omit that detail. As long as your code is compiled with debugging information or the `-parameters` compiler flag on Java 8, Spring MVC will match the method argument name to the URI template variable name:
>
> ```
> @GetMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
> public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
>     // implementation omitted
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

From documentation page which you mentioned:

> The URI Template "/owners/{ownerId}" specifies the variable name `ownerId. When the controller handles this request, the value of ownerId is set to the value found in the appropriate part of the URI. For example, when a request comes in for /owners/fred, the value of ownerId is fred.

So, if you don't want to specify value of @PathVariable use the same name of your method parameter and in the path template.